# How to recieve a Broker's data with an MQTT.fx client?

Tags: ssh, mqtt, remote-server, mosquitto, ssh-tunnel

I have both a client and a broker running on a remote Linux machine within a **Lora Network server** that has a mosquitto connector.

The client can listen for the broker's broadcast from a certain address and port (@`127.0.0.1:1883`)
I would like to open an ssh tunnel between this remote machine and my machine (windows 10) to 'eavesdrop' on the communication between the client and the broker using `MQTT.fx` to run a mosquitto client; 
So far I tried to:

1. Run `ssh -L 22883:@remoteMachineAdress:1883 usern.ame@gatewayAdress -p222` on MobaXtrem](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)
2. Then I launch a client on `MQTT.fx`  to listen on the broker: `127.0.0.1 port 22883`.

This establishes a connection to the broker. However, I am not receiving any of the messages passed to the original client (the one on the remote machine) receives.

**Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?**
**And if there are any tutorials about this?**

I appreciate all the help I can get, thank you in advance!

Comment: You haven't said 1) what topics you subscribed to 2) if there is any ACL on the broker that would limit what you can see if you log into the broker anonymously

Comment: @hardillb I'm subscribing to one topic to which I have a device publishing the temperature value, the client needs a username and a pass to connect that I already specify for the MQtt.fx client in the User credientials field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration is correct, it was the connector on the server who was sending the data to a different application.